# Chocolatey startup takes unpredictable time on Azure Pipelines (sometimes minutes)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, chocolatey

We use Chocolately in our Azure Pipelines setup. Chocolatey startup seems to take an unpredictable amount of time: it could be as short as seconds or as long as minutes.

In [this example](https://dev.azure.com/igraph-team/igraph/_build/results?buildId=968&view=logs&j=49ab37fe-0e63-51fc-3ac1-38d2115bd060&t=e171dc84-62b2-53d4-80a8-fa460969240b&l=12) it took 13 seconds, while [in this one](https://dev.azure.com/igraph-team/igraph/_build/results?buildId=968&view=logs&j=dc2fa7f2-c2a5-5af8-ba1c-9621505790a7&t=dc62210b-f1c9-5a27-9acf-5401b4b720ec&l=12) it took 2 minutes 20 seconds. It always gets stuck after the output line "Chocolatey v0.10.15", i.e. it seems that it is not package installation that takes long, but Chocolatey startup.

Questions:

- Is this expected with Azure Pipelines?
- Is there anything I can do about it, and make Chocolatey startup reasonably fast?

Comment: These complaints seem similar: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/chocolatey-is-really-slow-to-start-up-on-hosted-ag/1092893

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your logs, we find the [faster one](https://dev.azure.com/igraph-team/igraph/_build/results?buildId=968&view=logs&j=49ab37fe-0e63-51fc-3ac1-38d2115bd060&t=801b2382-3060-404d-bd24-739ecfa0d455) used the agent 'WIN-EHTFAB4ECBV', but the [another one](https://dev.azure.com/igraph-team/igraph/_build/results?buildId=968&view=logs&j=dc2fa7f2-c2a5-5af8-ba1c-9621505790a7&t=3b8f11ab-2c44-441a-ad13-0a0db4b6e397) used the agent 'fv-az238-568'. Since they use different self-agent, your issue may be caused by machine performance. You can try to use the [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to help you select the specified agent to run this pipeline.

Comment: It's surprising through that the difference in Chocolatey startup (and only startup!) is a factor of 10, but the difference in compilation time is only a factor of 1.2. Can this really be the result of machine performance?

Comment: But you are correct: there seems to be a correlation with the agent name. It is the `fv-` ones that are slow.

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs, we can try to set the 'agent.name' in the extends to use other agent to run the pipeline instead of using the 'fv-' ones. And dose my answer help you to solve your issue/confuse, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks